# how to write if condition for digit must be between 9 to 11 digit in react native

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native. And I want user to Put account number between 9 to 11 not grater than 11 digit or nor less than 9 digit. so how to do that.

here is my code

```
 validateInputs = () => {
      if (!this.state.accountNo.trim()) {
        this.setState({ accountError: 'Please enter account no' })
        return;
      }
      else {
        Alert.alert("All fields validated")
        return;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You may validate the account number against the regex pattern `^\d{9,11}$`:

```js
validateInputs = () => {
  if (!this.state.accountNo.trim()) {
    this.setState({ accountError: 'Please enter account no' })
    return;
  }
  if (!/^\d{9,11}$/.test(this.state.accountNo)) {
    this.setState({ accountError: 'Account no must be 9 to 11 digits' })
    return;
  }
  Alert.alert("All fields validated")
}
```

Side note: It is usually best practice to *not* inform outside users as to why their authentication attempt might have failed.  Revealing such information could lead to a security hole.

Comment: Ok thanks So How Could I do that for following Conditions =  ifsc code = The IFSC is an 11-character code with the first four alphabetic characters
representing the bank name,
and the last six characters (usually numeric, but can be alphabetic) representing the branch. 
The fifth character is 0 (zero) and reserved for future use.

Comment: mobile number = 
should not start with 0 and must have 10 digit

Comment: and for email id also

Comment: That's not what you asked above.

Comment: Here I have asked But the I do not get that answer = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845421/how-to-validate-all-input-on-single-submit-click-in-react-native

Answer (score 0):

So you can find out the number of digits in a line **replace(/\D+/g,'').length**

```
  validateInputs = () => {
      if (!this.state.accountNo.trim()) {
        this.setState({ accountError: 'Please enter account no' })
        return;
      }
      else if ((this.state.accountNo.trim().replace(/\D+/g,'').length>11)
    || (this.state.accountNo.trim().replace(/\D+/g,'').length<9)) {
        this.setState({ accountError: 'Account  must be contains from 9 to 11 digits' })
        return;
      }
      else {
        Alert.alert("All fields validated")
        return;
      }
    }
```

Comment: please help for this = https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845421/how-to-validate-all-input-on-single-submit-click-in-react-native